# Hyphenation never working

Tags: hyphenation

Do I have to do something special to turn hyphenation on?
My texts never get hyphenated.

For instance, the code below generates a document that is 15 pages long and not a single word is hyphenated.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

And I think it really could use some hyphens here and there. For instance, the word "meaning" in the image below:

[image]

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: I get an overfull line, but it ends with “mean-” (second line in page 14). Overfull boxes happen now and then and can be cured by rewording. However, I get hyphens, so maybe there's something in your TeX installation.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. That was my fear. Which system are you running?
I'm on Linux using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.11.17)
But I also tried LuaLaTex and no luck.

Comment: as @egreg said (see image I just posted) can you show the full log you get from your test document?

Comment: miktex on linux? Any particular reason for that almost all linux users will be using texlive, although it should work of course.

Comment: I ran this on MikTex on Windows 10 and got the same output as @DavidCarlisle.

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown much information but if I run your document I see this page

[image]

You will see several words are hypenated.

The over full box is flagged on the terminal

```
Overfull \hbox (5.96689pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--7
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 Hello, here is some text with-out a mean-
```

and is telling you that TeX can not find a good break here even allowing for hyphenation.

---

Your output is consistent with having a language with no hyphenation patterns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\language=100

    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

If you get that with the default US hypenation patterns then you must surely have had an error in the log when the format was built, as they are supposed to be always enabled.

Comment: Hi David, I checked the log and the only thing that seems related to hyphenation, was this line:

```0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191```

I sincerely cant understand whether this is a good or bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

The easiest way I can think of to make your test document generate the screenshot you posted is by loading the `hyphenat` package with the option `none`. Doing so completely disables hyphenation.

[image]

(the screenshot is taken from the top of p. 14.)

Hende, do please check if your document executes `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` or contains other instructions that disable hyphenation.

Comment: Good point, but the MWE that I posted was the whole .tex file.

Comment: @Miotto - "The whole tex file" *you* posted simply does *not* give rise to the screenshot you  posted. Instead, it gives rise to lots and lots of instances of hyphenated words. (See David Carlisle's first screenshot, say, for a proof of this assertion.)

Comment: Yes it *does*.\
(Or, better put, it *did*. I could solve the problem by reinstalling the tex system)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
However, I couldn't find out what exactly was causing it.

Basically, I followed David's and egreg's intuition that the problem may be in my distribution.

So, after running:

```
sudo apt remove miktex
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

the hyphenation started working again.

Thank you guys!

Comment: That fixes it for you by using a different system but you could probably report a bug at miktex if hyphenation is really broken in its linux version)

Comment: That is a good idea. I'll try to reproduce the problem in another computer using a clean and up to date version of MikTex. If I succeed, I'll open an issue.